# Must declare the scalar variable - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called CourceInstance which includes a Period and a Year attribute. I am trying to put the values of Period attribute from CourseInstance into my table variable. It can run without a problem however every time I run the `EXEC @tablePeriod` part or the whole code it gives me the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@tablePeriod".

What can the problem be of? @tablePeriod is already declared.

```
DECLARE @tablePeriod TABLE ( Period INT ) INSERT INTO @tablePeriod (Period)
SELECT Period FROM CourseInstance WHERE Year = 2015

EXEC @tablePeriod
```

Comment: Sure, it is declared, but it is not scalar, because it is a table-typed variable.

Comment: What do you expect `EXEC @tablePeriod` to *do*? I'm genuinely unable to guess what your intention was here.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I dont understand the meaning of scalar in this situation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbelieverto show a table including the values of Period from CourseInstance. Something like a view of the column  CourseInstance.Period

Comment: @Tomb_Raider_Legend "Scalar" means "with a single value", such as a single number or a single string. In this context that's the opposite of "table", which may have more than one value organized as rows and columns, or no values at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect

```
EXEC @tablePeriod
```

should be something like

```
select * from @tablePeriod
```

Then it won't return error but you have to run whole code in one block.

Running the code that uses the variable separately from the declaration statement is giving you error.

Edit: Now I guess I know what you want to achieve. Actually the DECLARE and INSERT statement are enough for that.
No need for something else.

Running

```
select * from @tablePeriod
```

in same block will show you that the values are inserted into table variable.

Comment: I am doing it as well but yet it gives me the error. I have declared this variabel many times before but stopped using it due to code failures. Now I am declaring it again in another project. The problem migh be because of that maybe?

Comment: The problem is at least in how you use it, the "EXEC".

Comment: thanks for the help. IT works. But in which situation do you use EXEC on the variabel? I only seen people do it in some other examples

Comment: @Tomb_Raider_Legend In case of Dynamic SQL, for instance. I.e. `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max); SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM @myTable'; EXEC @SQL`. You'd typically use something like this in situations where you perform operations on different tables. Think of a loop in which you do some table or column modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with tempory table. I think tempory table is better than table variable.

```
SELECT Period INTO #tablePeriod FROM CourseInstance WHERE Year = 2015;
SELECT * FROM #tablePeriod;
```

Comment: Why would you argue it's better? What's the motivation?

Comment: @SchmitzIT
Both have advantages and disadvantages.I only mean for above question because code is much shorter and no need to create extra table varible. I don't mean for all condition.  

I add link for reference of performance

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2825/sql-server-temp-table-vs-table-variable-performance-testing/